# Underscores are understood as subindixes in italic letter at matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, italic

I'm plotting some text in a figure with `ax.text()` method, of matplotlib. Nevertheless, if the string `var` contains underscores, this are understood as subindixes.

Is this a bug to report? Or am I doing something wrong.
I have already tried with '\033[3m' characters, but no italic letter show up. Since not all the text goes in italic, I cannot change rc.Params.

Any aid is appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
var = 'Hello_12'
text = f"Dataset: ${var}$"
ax.text(0.5,0.5, text)
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the underscores to be preserved literally? And do you want to get italic text?

Comment: Do you know, that the dollars "$" do not only make the text in italics, but enters the Latex math environment? There, you can escape the underscore with "\_". The problem is, that numbers are not in italics in this math environment. There should however be another way to get italic text in matplotlib

Comment: That's it, I want to keep the underscorse and turn 'var' content into italic text.
Thanks for the input @Libavius, I didn't know. I'd like to turn numbers into italic too, so maybe Latex is not the way, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the text to be italic, you could provide the `style` keyword argument to the `Axes.text` method:

```py
var = 'Hello_12'
text = f"Dataset: {var}"
ax.text(0.5,0.5, text, style='italic')
```

By doing it in this way, you don't need to use TeX formatting. Hence, the underscore will be preserved instead of interpreting the character after the underscore to be a subscript.

#### **Edit**

After the comment of `@Miguel Gonzalez`, I propose the following solution. Note however that this does require you to have a LaTeX installation.

Consider the code below:

```py
var = 'Hello\_12'
text = r"Dataset: $\mathit{" + var + "}$"
ax.text(0.5,0.5, text, usetex=True)
```

First of all, the <kbd>_</kbd> character in `var` must be escaped using a  <kbd>\</kbd> . Secondly, we want to use `\mathit` to get italic text in math modus. Note that I declared this as a raw string (`r"..."`) to prevent additional escape characters. Lastly, we supply the `usetex` keyword argument with a value `True` to the  `Axes.text` method. This will produce the following output:
[image: output italic text]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DeX97, but this way all the text is turned into italic, when I only want the 'var' content in italic

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez I posted an update. Is this the behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: Yes @DeX97, that's it. It would be nice to make it work with out LaTex, but for the moment is great. Thank you very much.